# Convertion of Floating Value to Int 0.345 to 345 in java language

Tags: java

i am using Math.random() method but method return a double Value so wana Convert 0.345 to 345 and between ranges like 50 --- 100 only.

Comment: I suggest you use `java.util.Random` instead...

Comment: So multiply by a factor?

Comment: How are you going to convert to 345 and stay in the range 50-100?

Comment: `Random r = new Random(50);
r.random() + 50;`

Comment: What do you mean by `between ranges like 50 --- 100 only`?

Comment: To Convert 0.345 to 345 `double d=0.345; int i=(int)(d)*1000;`

Answer (score 0):

You can go with Random class and give Min and Max according to the range random value you required :

```
  Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1))
```